# Problem paginating a subquery on a post

Tags: posts, theme-development, pagination

I have created a post template that looks for other posts with the same tags. I want to paginate this list of posts. The pagination links look correct but when I click on them the pagination is lost.

For example the page is mywebsite/category/postname and the second page link points to /mywebsite/category/postname/page/2 but when I click on it the URL in the browser address bar goes back to mywebsite/category/postname.

Using similar code on a page template seems to work so not sure why it is not working on a post

The code I am using in the template is as follows:

```
<?php


get_header(); ?>

<div class="container container--has-padding">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
<div class="single-post-hero" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $url ?>);">
&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="hero-caption"><?php the_field('hero_caption'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="single-post-meta">
        <?php the_category(', '); ?>
    </div>
    <h1 class="single-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div class="single-post-share-top">
        <?php include '../includes/share.php'; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="single-post-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    </div>

<div class="posts-archive container section">

    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    echo 'Currently Browsing Page ', $paged;



    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

    if ($tags) {
    $tag_ids = array();
    foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
    $args=array(
    'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=>10, // Number of related posts to display.
    'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    global $loop;
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        ?>
        <h2 class="text-center">Posts about this manufacturer</h2>
        <ul class="grid">
        <?php
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>

        <li class="grid__column grid__column--third">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $url ?>);">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
            <h3 class="grid-posts-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
        </li>

    <?php 
        endwhile;


    ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="pager">
        <ul>
        <?php

        $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

        if ($total_pages > 1){

            $args = array(
                'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                'format' => 'page/%#%',
                'total' => $total_pages,
                'current' => $paged,
                'show_all' => false,
                'end_size' => 3,
                'mid_size' => 2,
                'prev_next' => True,
                'prev_text' => __('&lsaquo;'),
                'next_text' => __('&rsaquo;'),
                'type' => 'list',
                );
            echo paginate_links($args);

        }
        ?>
        </ul>
<?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>


    <?php if( get_field('show_standard_advert') ): ?>

        <div class="advert">
            <?php the_field('news_category_advert_shortcode','options'); ?>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="advert">
        <?php the_field('post_specific_advert_shortcode'); ?>
    </div>




<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `paged` parameter to your args for `WP_Query`?

```
$args=array(
   'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
   'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
   'posts_per_page'=>10, // Number of related posts to display.
   'caller_get_posts'=>1,
   'paged' => $paged
);
```

Comment: Thanks yes tried that but makes no difference. The pagination doesn't seem to get back to the post it is lost somehow. The pagination links created look correct but the /page/n is lost when you click on them.